# Near analysis for nearest feature in a distinct angle

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, proximity

I want to calculate the nearest distance from a point feature to a line feature in a distinct angle.

When using the Near analysis tool in ArcGIS I get the nearest distance in a angle where the nearest feature lies. In the picture below for -170°.

But I want to be able to calculate the distance for different angles for example for 90° or 180°.
Someone an idea how I could solve this? I'm also capable of creating my own script with python.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created this tool that may help?

http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=2b0c54fe415641e7af8490c4ba7d4bcf

As a side note it is always worth checking out arcscripts before posting here.

Create your bearing lines, run an intersect to create intersection points and pass over ids then run the near tool or use pyrhon to get distances.

Comment: great thank you also thought about that way afterwards.